# What does 算你狠 mean?

Tags: translation, slang

I've been pondering on this one for a while, but I'm still not sure about the best wording for it. It seems to be often used by someone who has been defeated/humiliated/etc, implying something along the lines of "you're quite something" / "you got me!" / "you win!" / "kudos to you" but with a certain negative/derogatory undertone.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English. Chinese SE caters for people learning the Chinese Language. It is never a site for people to learn English.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic. OP wants to know the meaning of 算你狠. I think it's still within the realm of learning the Chinese language. Unfortunately, I've rarely ever heard it used. I'm guessing it's some slang. Some online answers are "You're cruel / bad / ruthless / relentless", "Damn you", "You win". I can't tell if it's sarcastic or if it means something like "shame on you". Is it similar to 你好坏? (which can be said in jest)

Comment: I hear it all the time and this is definitely offtopic. "You win" or "This is not over" would be two appropriate translations for this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for English Language & Usage because it is about Chinese. EL&U caters for people learning the English Language. It is never a site for people to learn Chinese

Comment: Hanxue, since asking questions about both English and Chinese are going to be off-topic on Chinese for including English and off-topic on English for including Chinese, just reword your entire question to ask "Please explain what this means".

Comment: @hippietrail, I disagree. From the question, OP already knows what it means and is seeking for the "best wording". If she really wants, she can always post in EL&U asking how to express "you win", but with the emotion "you only win because you over-do it brutally". In Chinese with have this expression 算你狠... CL&U users shouldn't be inundated with English word/phrase/slang requests from users whose only purpose is to improve their English vocabulary.

Comment: Yes if the OP doesn't want to rephrase it because they really do just want a translation then it should be closed and deleted. But if they do rephrase it then it should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 5):

It literally just means "consider you to be brutal". Maybe "you're brutal" or "that's brutal" fits better for English speakers.

Interestingly both characters [狠](https://www.moedict.tw/%E7%8B%A0) and [很](https://www.moedict.tw/%E5%BE%88) share a common meaning that they both mean "brutal", or "cruel". However in some scenarios brutal/cruel might be too much, maybe you can seek some thesaurus from the tangent of "很", meaning "very" (adj), "too much".

It's more like expressing "you win", but with the emotion saying "you only win because you over-do it brutally". But when it is physical rather then mental, 狠 would mean "aggressively" or "violently".

However, it can be used as a admiration between friends expressing "you accomplish this job in a awesome way, although that feels a bit overkill. 算你狠" -- In this sense that'll be more like "you're the man" kind of expression.

Answer (score 0):

别人要求自己做自己不想做的事情，而又没有办法拒绝，不用于长辈与晚辈之间。多用于朋友之间和仇人之间(Ps:编辑又麻烦你了，不好意思。)

Answer (score 0):

It can mean many things , if you're bullied or beaten up or lost a big deal to someone, you can use this phrase to express your anger and also it slightly implies your weakness. Because `算你狠` so please just leave me alone.

Or it can mean you admire someone you like or close to you

> -我居然是第一名(I can't believe I am the champion!)
>
> -算你狠(Congratulations!)

Answer (score -1):

For example，when you are bullied, you can speak this phrase to the bully.It shows your anger and admits that you can't defeat him by yourself.